# How to upgrade angularjs service with angular 5.2

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, ng-upgrade

What is currently the correct way to upgrade an angularjs service in a hybrid angularjs 1.4/angular 5.2 application so that i can use it in a component as a provider?

Both code bases are typescript and i use the new downgradeModule to downgrade angular components in order to keep the number of digests in check and don't want to ruin this.

I have a generated type definition file for the angular js app so that all classes can be assumed to be accessable.

**EDIT:**
I have tried wrapping the services in an object like a ValueProvider (I had to wrap the whole thing in another object with a getter and setter to return it in order to hide the function call from Angular, which do not like function calls in decorators). Heres code without the trixing to explain the idea.

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: MyNamespace.MyService,
    useValue: angular.element("body").injector().get("myService")
  }
]
```

But I then get errors when trying to inject it in a component constructor.

If I only add it to the constructor I get: `[Angular] Can't resolve all parameters for SeparatorComponent in d:/Source/Prevero/Everest/src/com/prevero/everest/oneclient/src/modules/app_components/separators/separator.component.ts: (?)`.

If I add it to the providers array I get `[Angular] Invalid providers for "SeparatorComponent in d:/Source/Prevero/Everest/src/com/prevero/everest/oneclient/src/modules/app_components/separators/separator.component.ts" - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?null?]`